# Git Bash eating last character on each line

Tags: bash, git, github

I am having a problem with Git Bash on Windows. It is always eating the last character on every line which wraps, leading me to sometimes having a repeated letter in my commit messages. Any ideas on how to solve this?

You can see this in the example below, the commit message is correct but not fully displayed.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured out what the problem was. This only happens when the console overflows, which is why that initial letter g is there. Essentially the program doesn't know that initial g is there, but it still terminates the line after the same amount of characters, so the last letter is swallowed. However, it does not ignore your input, it just doesn't display it.

Comment: I suspect you have a "bug" in your prompt with properly containing colour codes. show `echo "$PS1"`

Comment: @VonC it's because I type while it's running something like git add, which is aliased to ga.

Comment: @glennjackman \[\033[0;35m\]\u\[\033[0;32m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[0;34m\] \W $ \[\033[0m\]

Comment: You are missing `\[` and `\]` around all the "invisible" colour codes. Try this: `PS1='\[[\e[0;35m]\]\u\[[\e[0;32m]\]$(__git_ps1)\[[\e[0;34m]\] \W $ \[[\e[0m]\]'` -- that will help bash determine how wide your prompt actually is. (`\e` is equal to `\033` in your PS1 -> [6.9 Controlling the Prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt))

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks. I notice it now conforms to how wide the window is, cool!